# Non automatic structure, which is decidable

Tags: logic, computer-science, formal-languages, regular-language

I know that $(\mathbb{N}, \cdot)$ and $(\mathbb{N}, |)$ are non automatic, but also not decidable. I also now that every automatic structure is decidable. Now I am curious if there is a non automatic structure, which is decidable, or if the previous sentence is iff.

> A relational structure $\mathcal{A}$ is called automatic if there is a regular language $L$ and a surjective function $\nu: L \to A$ such that the following languages are regular:
>
> $L_\epsilon := \{(w, w') \in L \times L | \nu(w) = \nu(w')\}$
>
> $L_R := \{ w \in L^r | (\nu(w_1),...,\nu(w_r))\in R\}$ for all relations $R \subseteq A^r$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to your first sentence, arithmetic with just multiplication ("[Skolem arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_arithmetic)") **is decidable**. (Compare with [Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic), the also-decidable reduct of arithmetic to just *addition*.) In general, automaticity is a very strong structural property (consider e.g. the Constant Growth Lemma) and we can whip up decidable structures which are still "combinatorially nasty" and thus not automatic.